# Updating some fields in main activity after exiting from another activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

My `MainActivity` has an `EditText` with the hint "`Weight (lb)`", as well as a button that goes to the `SettingsActivity`. In `SettingsActivity`, the user is able to change the units used from US to metric. Upon exiting `SettingsActivity` via the built-in back button on the phone, I want the hint for the `EditText` to immediately change from "`Weight (lb)`" to "`Weight (kg)`".

The farthest I've gotten is using the `onBackPressed()` method in `SettingsActivity`. The button press is detected, and the code inside it is executed, but I don't want to change anything related to `MainActivity`'s inside the `SettingsActivity` class.

Is there an `on___()` method that I should be using here that I don't know about? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using an intent in `onBackPressed()`? Something that says from `SettingsActivity` to `MainActivity`? This will cause `MainActivity` to reload the hint. I am assuming that the hint is being stored somewhere though.

Comment: @DanielK The hint is stored in the `android:hint` field of the `EditText` in question. Is that the best place to store it? In addition, how would I use an Intent on `onBackPressed()`?

Comment: How is it stored? If you're using SharedPreferences then you can use the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Easy option is to store the waitUnit in shared preference and on OnResume() of the Main activity read it from there and update the widget.

You can update the preferences in your Settings activity like below:

```
preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getString(R.string.preference_file_key),
                        Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
preferences.edit().putString("unit", "kg");
```

And you can read this changed value in OnResume() of your Main Activity

```
preferences.getString("unit", "default unit")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use startActivityForResult for SettingsActivity and after that handle the return result as:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
    // Make sure the request was successful
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // The user picked a contact.
        // The Intent's data Uri identifies which contact was selected.

        // Do something with the contact here (bigger example below)
    }
```

}

More detail: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use startActivityForResult for SettingsActivity and after that handle the return result as:

In your MainActivity:

```
public static int CALL_SETTINGS = 1000;
startActivityForResult(new Intent(this,SettingsActivity.class),CALL_SETTINGS);

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
 if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
// Make sure the request was successful
   if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
      // The user picked a contact.
      // The Intent's data Uri identifies which contact was selected.

     // Do something with the contact here (bigger example below)
  }
}

In your Settings Activity:
 on backpressed write this:

 Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
 returnIntent.putExtra("result",data);
 setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
 finish();
```